# Concatenate and sort two int arrays in to one int array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I know a similar question has been asked and I have researched this website. I have tried to use some of the answers but my syntax is still not working.

I am going through a previous examination paper to help build my knowledge of Java.
Please forgive any errors in my code, I am still learning the Java syntax.

Here is my question:

Implement a method static int[] splice(int[] v, int[] w) that (assuming the lengths of v and w are the same) returns an array in which the elements if v and w are interleaved, starting with the first element of v, followed by the first element of w, followed by the second element of v, etc.
For example, if v = { 1, 3, 5 } and w = { 2, 4, 6 } the call splice should  return { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.

If the input arrays have different lengths, the method should return null.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TwoArraysBecomeOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] v = { 1, 3, 5 };
    int[] w = { 2, 4, 6 };

    splice(v,w);
}

public static int[] splice(int[] v, int[] w){

    if(v != w) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] x = new int[v.length + w.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        x[i] = v[i] + w[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(x[j]);
    }

    return x;

    }
}
```

I am aware that my current syntax is producing a new array x = { 3, 7, 11 }.
I have removed the various attempts to try and concatenate my code as this was causing errors in my code. I just require some pointers to help answer this question.

Again, please forgive any errors in my code, I am still learning Java.

Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work about this code?

Comment: The current array x is required to produce { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }. It is returning { 3, 7, 11 }.

Comment: that example, `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }` seems to contradict the previous description of the problem

Comment: you probably want to compare length of array here: `if(v != w){ return null; }`

Comment: There appears to be an error in the question, the expected output of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` does not match the description of interleaving them: "The first element of v followed by the first element of w and the second element of v...". Which behavior is desired? Interleaving them or merging and sorting? Based on the problem the expected output should be: `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`

Comment: `if(v != w) return null;` does not compare the lengths. It compares the references. To compare the lengths use `v.length != w.length`

Comment: Apologies. The result needs to take the two int arrays, v and w, put them together in numerical order. So, x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] v = { 1, 3, 5 };
    int[] w = { 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] res = splice(v, w);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
}

private static int[] splice(int[] v, int[] w) {
    if (v.length != w.length) {
        return null;
    }
    int[] a = new int[v.length + w.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        a[i * 2] = v[i];
        a[i * 2 + 1] = w[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Ignore previous comment. Created new for loop below the for loop that actually creates a[] and it is great!! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Sorry about that.

Comment: With regards to the syntax a[i * 2] = v[i] and   a[i * 2 + 1] = w[i] - What is the v[i] and w[i] doing in this algorithm? Or is it just required syntax?
I only ask so that I can get my head around it. Thank you.

Comment: When i=0, `a[0]=v[0]` and a `a[1]=w[0]`, when i=1, `a[2]=v[1]` and `a[3]=w[1]`.  Does that help?

Comment: i=0: a[0]=v[0]; a[1]=w[0] so a = [1,2,0,0,0,0]; i=1: a[2]=v[1]; a[3]=w[1] so a = [1,2,3,4,0,0]; ...

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks. Its just so that I can see how it works. =]

Answer (score 2):

You just have a small error, you don't want to be summing the elements of the arrays, but placing them side by side in the new array

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    x[i*2] = v[i];
    x[i*2+1] = w[i];
}
```